# Does VMware centralized supports image repository like OpenStack Glance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, openstack

Like OpenStack Glance or AWS AMI, Does VMware Vcenter provides any service for archiving the images.If not what's the recommend method in Vcentre/Esxi based Datacentre

Answer (score 2):

Content Libraries is what you're after - you can even use them via Glance if you're running Openstack for VMware.

Comment: My setup is  Vcenter with Exsi hosts, where i spin up the instances.Not VMware OpenStack

Comment: I understand that, just saying that you *CAN* do it that way